# Dynamic Object's property set

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, asp.net-core

Below is my function :

```
    public static StoreMetaData SetUpdateTime(dynamic myObject)
    {
        var storeMetaData = new StoreMetaData
        {
            Created = myObject["StoreMetaData"]["Created"], //Facing problem
            Updated = DateTime.Now
        };
        return storeMetaData;
    }
```

I have three objects :

1. Teacher

   Properties :

   ```
             public string id{get;set;}
             public string name{get;set;}
             public StoreMetaData storeMetaData{get;set;}
   ```
2. Student

   Properties :

   ```
             public string id{get;set;}
             public string name{get;set;}
             public StoreMetaData storeMetaData{get;set;}
   ```
3. StoreMetaData

   Properties :

   ```
             public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
             public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
   ```

My problem is how I can get "Created = myObject["StoreMetaData"]["CreatedDate"]".

I want to pass my objects in that function like below:

Part of my code :

```
            teacherObj.StoreMetaData.Created = (currentObject.StoreMetaData != null ? currentObject.StoreMetaData.Created : null);
            teacherObj.storeMetaData = SetUpdateTime(teacherObj);
```

OR,

```
            studentObj.StoreMetaData.Created = (currentObject.StoreMetaData != null ? currentObject.StoreMetaData.Created : null);
            studentObj.storeMetaData = SetUpdateTime(studentObj);
```

At line "Created = myObject["StoreMetaData"]["CreatedDate"]" it shows error. What is the correct format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should probably have an interface (or base class) describing the common properties you need to access. I'd also strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by me. Thanks every one. :)
Below is my solution :

```
    public static StoreMetaData SetUpdateTime(dynamic myObject)
    {
        StoreMetaData oStoreMetaData = new StoreMetaData();
        oStoreMetaData = myObject.StoreMetaData;
        var storeMetaData = new StoreMetaData
        {
            Created = oStoreMetaData.Created,
            Updated = DateTime.Now
        };
        return storeMetaData;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on the code you posted, your issue is that the storeMetaData property is defined with a lower case first letter, but when you try to access it, you specify it as upper-case.

Try `Created = myObject["storeMetaData"]["CreatedDate"];`

As an aside, I'm not sure if indexers work like that on dynamic objects. I think they do, but just in case I would use dot syntax as you're dealing with properties.

`Created = myObject.storeMetaData.CreatedDate;`

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you are passing an object of `Teacher` or `Student` so that it contains definition for `storeMetaData` from that you can access `Created` which is a property defined inside the `StoreMetaData` class. Indexers won't help you at this stage, you should use like this:

```
Created = myObject.StoreMetaData.Created;
```